# Virtual meeting vs teleconference

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, differences, terminology

How did the word "virtual" come to mean "Operating by computer or in cyberspace; not physically present"?

Virtual, to me, means "not real", but when we're working form home, having "virtual meetings" or when we have a video call with our doctor for a "virtual check-up", it's still a meeting, it's still a check-up. What would make it virtual?

I think it would be more accurately termed a "teleconference", "telemedicine", or just "telepresence", much like our old familiar friends, telephone, television, telescope, telegraph, teletype, etc, and common sci-fi and fantasy tropes such as teleportation, telekinesis, and telepathy.

If we were all in VR Chat with our 3D headsets and motion capture suits like in Ready Player One, with simulated AI meeting participants and some fictional agenda, I might feel more comfortable calling it a "virtual meeting" but let's be serious, it's a teleconference, it's telecommunication. It's real, not virtual.

Comment: But the voice you're talking to, or the image you're seeing, *isn't* real. It's just a representation of a real person in a different location. So, you're not having a *real* in-person meeting, you're having a *virtual* meeting.

Answer (score 1):

I work in SaaS, and the term "Virtualisation" came up yesterday! As in, "we recently virtualised the production and pre-production environments." I looked it up in order to be able to explain to clients, and it turns out *virtualisation* is technology that allows multiple simulated environments using resources that are traditionally bound to hardware. 
To extrapolate that into the human work force, you can see how working virtually means working without a physical presence.

I think you could look at teleconferencing as how you connect to your virtual team, so a teleconference is the form of communication. An important distinction because you're not always working on a call/meeting when you're working remotely.